# Exception trying to Update Service reference!

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

I have a Silverlight Application that use a WebService for MultPorpose,
When i usa that markers:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(StringCustomField))]
```

In on of my classes i get that error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
 contract: SCI4WebService ----> **System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml**, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, RuntimeTypeHandle* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.Module.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, Module decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(Module decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.TryGetDCAttribute(Type type, DataContractAttribute& dataContractAttribute)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(Type type, Boolean& hasDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetCollectionStableName(Type type, Type itemType, CollectionDataContractAttribute& collectionContractAttribute)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.CollectionDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type, CollectionKind kind, Type itemType, MethodInfo getEnumeratorMethod, MethodInfo addMethod, ConstructorInfo constructor)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.IsCollectionOrTryCreate(Type type, Boolean tryCreate, DataContract& dataContract, Type& itemType, Boolean constructorRequired)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.TryCreate(Type type, DataContract& dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.GetDataContract(Type clrType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.GetMemberTypeDataContract(DataMember dataMember)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddCollectionDataContract(CollectionDataContract collectionDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddCollectionDataContract(CollectionDataContract collectionDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.Export(Type type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportType(Type type, String partName, String operationName, XmlSchemaType& xsdType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractExporter.ExportBody(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessage(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessageContract()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.Get(Message message)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</PRE></DIV></BODY></HTML>
--.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:1071/SCI4WebService.svc'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:1071/SCI4WebService.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I have no ideas, try to reference XML namespace in all projects and nothing!!!

Help!!

Looking for a answer i see that:

i have two System.Xml on my machine:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll - 2.0.0.0

C:\Arquivos de programas\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v2.0\ReferenceAssemblies\System.Xml.dll - 2.0.0.5

Is this my problem????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was your framework version recently updated? It could be that the System.XML dlls were replaced by a newer version of them (since the error indicates that it is looking for version 2.0.5.0) and you'd need to update your web.config or System.Xml references to make sure it's using the newer version.

Comment: I change Service reference to lookup to Silverlight System.Xml vrsion and solve my problem tanks!!